# cannot load such file -- mysql12 (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby script that I have written and I am trying to use if to write to an active record database that I have created. When I add a require 'mysql12' to the file I get the following error:

> .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:106:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql12 (LoadError)

When I do a

```
gem list | grep mysql
activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
```

it shows that the mysql12 gem is installed.

My database.yml file for the project looks like this:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
```

Comment: Should it be `require 'mysql12'` or `require 'mysql2'`?

Comment: I believe it should be  require 'mysql12'

Comment: You were right, I'm embrassed to say that I had a 12 in mysql intead of mysql2. Please make it an offical answer so that I can give you credit for it.  Thanks

Comment: Nice!  There you go, added an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I add a require 'mysql12' to the file I get the following error:
>
> .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:106:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- mysql12 (LoadError).

As commented above updating the `require` statement to `require 'mysql2'` in your ruby script should fix the error.